# How to convert an ascii code to its equivalent virtual key?

Tags: python, keyboard, key, ascii

I'm trying to write a code where every alphanumeric key you press, it gets converted to some other key. But the problem I'm facing is I can't convert an ascii value to its equivalent virtual key. Is there an inbuilt function which does so? If not then how do I write such a function?

My code:

```
from pynput import keyboard
from pynput.keyboard import Key,Controller

def on_press(key):
    try:
        Controller().press(some_inbuilt_or_manual_function(ord(str(key.char))+65280-32))
    except AttributeError:
        pass

if __name__=='__main__':
    with keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
        listener.join()
```

I'm currently coding in python, but I'd appreciate it if you could help me write similar code in java as well.

Comment: why are you using this `ord(str(key.char))+65280-32)`  ASCII only has 128 characters, can you explain what exactly are you trying to do with an example

Comment: Doesn't it have characters upto 65535? I thought the unicode has ascii values upto that range.

Comment: Does calling just `Controller().press(key)` in the try block not work? The [listener](https://pynput.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html#pynput.keyboard.Listener)  should be called with a `Key` or `KeyCode`, which is the same as [Controller.press](https://pynput.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html#pynput.keyboard.Controller.press)

Comment: It works but I want to make the computer press another character different from `key`. How do I do that?